# type mismatch in class template declaration

Tags: c++, stl

I am developing a simple configurator class using STL, but I am a little stuck with an issue, here is the code that in the base clase implements CRTP to avoid virtual interface declaration:

```
template<typename Tipo, typename Salida >
class ITipos{
public:
    Salida & convertir()
    {

        Salida aTipoSalida= static_cast<Tipo *>(this)->convertir_imp();
        return aTipoSalida;
    }

protected:
    bool mconversionOk;
};

template<typename Tipoentrada,typename TipoSalida >
class TipoString : public ITipos<TipoString,TipoSalida>
{
    using ITipos<TipoString,TipoSalida>::mconversionOk;
public:
    TipoString()
    {
        mconversionOk=false;
    }
    TipoSalida & convertir_imp()
    {
        TipoSalida aTipoSalida;
        return aTipoSalida;
    }
}
```

The problem is in the declaration of the TipoString class, the compiler doesn't like this declaration:

```
template<typename Tipoentrada,typename TipoSalida >
class TipoString : public ITipos<TipoString,TipoSalida>
```

The message from the compiler is:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list
>   for ‘template class ITipos’

The client code is:

```
 TipoBase<std::string> * aTipoBase= new Tipo<std::string,float>;
```

The intention  of the interface is to permit the transformation from a tipe to any type, using the above declaration, because using the normal attempt (declaring a virtual interface will explicitly offer method that performs conversion from types (string -> float,.. ,etc)), the interface will grow, and it will not be flexible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referencing a template as the parameter to `ITipos`, not a class.
Change it to:

```
template<typename Tipoentrada,typename TipoSalida >
class TipoString : public ITipos<TipoString<Tipoentrada, TipoSalida>,TipoSalida>
{
    using ITipos<TipoString<Tipoentrada, TipoSalida>,TipoSalida>::mconversionOk;
    /*...*/
};
```